# Sonar Component view and cobertura code coverage report view differ

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, cobertura

When I look at my Sonar Components view I see a lot of classes with code coverage. However, when I click the unit test code coverage percentile to retrieve the view of packages from which the percentile is derived from, I only get a subset of the covered packages/classes that are listed in the Components view. So Components view contains all classes in code coverage view, but code coverage view is a subset of the code covered classes in the Components view.

Any ideas what would make this like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see all the classes on the code coverage drilldown page because classes which have 100% code coverage are hidden (as there's nothing to do about them). On the other side, the component page shows all the components, whatever their measures on specific metrics are.

This is a general behaviour in Sonar. You can find all the classes though the components page, because this service is made to navigate through your code. But in the drilldown pages (measures or violations based), you will only see classes which have "issues" because this service is made to hunt quality flaws.

- in violation drilldown, you won't see classes which don't have any violation
- in measure drilldown, you won't see classes which have the "best value" for the selected metric (=> 100% for code coverage for instance)